# Isolating headers in Python 3 CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to take the data from a CSV file in Python 3 and do some calculations with it, but before that I have to isolate the headers so that the loop doesn't try to use them to do the calculations. Currently my code looks like

```
import csv
filename = "superheroes_tiny.csv"
f = open(filename, "r")    
line = f.readline()
while line:
    niceline = line.strip().split(",")
    print(niceline)
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

This works to print out all of the values, but I need to be able to ignore the headers, and I don't know how.

edit - I got around it by just having it iterate down an extra line before the loop began - however, this feels like it likely isn't the most precise or neatest way to do this, and any other methods would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> iterate down an extra line before the loop began

That's exactly how to skip the headers.

Alternatively, you should read the file using pandas and then you have a dataframe object that can be referenced by header column names for computation